# Would search engine spam still be a problem even if every incoming click were to cost money?

Tags: incentives

Search engine spam can be thought of as any activity that seeks to gain attention for a web page through deceptive means. I suspect that search engine spam is a natural result of profit-maximizing behavior of webmasters in the absence of a per-click cost for each incoming click.

In other words, if every incoming click were to cost the webmaster a certain amount, then it stands to reason that he or she would have the incentive to not be deceptive, as getting clicks through deceptive means would result in a high bounce rate, which would be a waste of money.

Is this correct?

Comment: This is not a new idea. See e.g. this 2005 NYT article: https://www.nytimes.com/2005/02/13/business/yourmoney/how-to-stop-junk-email-charge-for-the-stamp.html

Comment: @KennyLJ It is an interesting article, but I'm more interested in search engine spam.